# Error "an expected string or bytes-like object error"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

below are mentioned codes which I used in jupyter notebook. However there appear one error while running the code. Could you please help me to debugg the error?

```
def split(string, delimiters= [" ","_",":"], maxsplit=0):
    regexPattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, delimiters))
    string = re.sub('\d','',string)
    string = re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', string)
    string = camel_case_split(string)
    str_spl = re.split(regexPattern, string, maxsplit)
    return [x for x in str_spl if x != '' and len(x)>1 and x not in beast_labels and x.lower() not in stopwords]
         
documents['split_doc'] = documents['BrandMetric'].apply(lambda x: split(x))
documents['split_clean'] = documents['BrandMetric'].apply(lambda x: split(x))
```

Error:- an expected string or bytes-like object error.

Answer (score -1):

This error says that `string` is expected to be either `str` or `bytes` objects, but it wasn't. And this happens if your `documents["BrandMetric"]` column has a list in it instead of a text.

So, to fix that, you can add this line at the start of your `split()` method:

```
def split(string, delimiters= [" ","_",":"], maxsplit=0):
    if type(string) == list:
        string = " ".join(string)
    regexPattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, delimiters))
    ...
    ...
```